# Update Composite Key On Duplicate Key

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I need to update new row just if both: `date='$dat'` and `empId='$who` ( as composite key ) . But insert if one of them or both differ:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO history 
       SET endtimestamp='$now',end='$signature',date='$dat',empId='$who' 
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE endtimestamp='$now',end='$signature'";
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Do you have a unique key on those fields?

Comment: both are primary key

Comment: So whats the problem.

Comment: if date != '$dat' or empId != '$who ( note its not equal != ) , its update not insert new one

Comment: I NEED it to update if 2 both are equal and insert if both or one of them differ !

Comment: equal to what? Each other? Or another row?

Comment: date = '$dat' and empId = '$who'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a **UNIQUE index** or **PRIMARY KEY**, an
>   UPDATE of the old row is performed.

A primary key is individual (per column). You need to create a composite UNIQUE index containing both columns, then the update will work correctly.

Run this on the database:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_employee_id_date ON history (empId, date);
```

Comment: Could you please run `SHOW INDEX FROM history;` and post the output so I can see what indexes are set on the table?

Comment: history 0 PRIMARY 1 empId A NULL NULL NULL BTREE history 0
PRIMARY 2 date A 2 NULL NULL BTREE
history 0 date 1 date A 2 NULL NULL BTREE
history 0 unq_employee_id_date 1 empId A NULL NULL NULL BTREE
history 0 unq_employee_id_date 2 date A 2 NULL NULL BTREE
history 1 empId 1 empId A NULL NULL NULL BTREE

Comment: I did not know you already had a composite primary key set up which should work fine. It is likely the other indexes causing a problem. Run these commands to remove the other indexes and try again: `ALTER TABLE history DROP INDEX \`unq_employee_id_date\``, `ALTER TABLE history DROP INDEX \`date\``, `ALTER TABLE history DROP INDEX \`empId\``